# Why does enabling Dyanamic Compression on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7) require 64bit, vs IIS 7 (Windows 2008)?

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio, iis-7, iis-7.5

I noticed that dynamic compression was not working correctly on my local machine for the app I'm developing.  It's a WCF REST Service, running in an application pool with "Allow 32 bit applications" enabled.  I noticed this in the applicationHost.config:

```
<add name="DynamicCompressionModule" image="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll" preCondition="bitness64" />
```

However, on our development server, I noticed that the corresponding line didn't contain the bitness64 precondition:

```
<add name="DynamicCompressionModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll" />
```

with the same application pool configuration.

In our local machines, we run IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 Ultimate.  In our development enviornment, we're running IIS 7 on Windows 2008 Server.  Currently our project is targeting "Any CPU".  I can get dynamic compression to work locally 2 ways:

1) Targeting x64 in the project.
2) Changing the application pool to NOT allow 32 bit applications.

As far as I can tell, the w3wp process on the development server is running in 32bit mode.

So I'm wondering if this is a new issue with IIS 7.5?  Anybody else run into this?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you have to make it a two step process and specifically target x64?  AnyCPU + changing the app pool to not run in x86 mode should sufice

Comment: That was not meant to look like a 2 step process, those were 2 different solutions that I tried that worked.  I'm wondering why IIS 7 is differing from IIS 7.5 in this way.  Sorry for the confusion.